# How to put this queries together?

Tags: sql

```
UPDATE [PipeLine] SET [PipeLine].[Building Rating] = 'A-'
WHERE ((([PipeLine].[NDA Status])<>'No' And ([PipeLine].[Building Status])<>'No') AND (([PipeLine].[Deal With Partner])<>'No') AND (([PipeLine].LAND)<>'No') AND (([PipeLine].Connect)<>'No'));

UPDATE [PipeLine] SET [PipeLine].[Building Rating] = 'B'
WHERE ((([PipeLine].[Building Status])<>'No' And ([PipeLine].[Building Status])<>'No') AND (([PipeLine].[Deal With Partner])<>'No'));
```

Comment: And before you run that query, note that you have duplicate and possibly mistyped logic: `([PipeLine].[Building Status])<>'No' And ([PipeLine].[Building Status])<>'No'`.

Comment: all run fine, just how to put them together

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE [PipeLine] 
SET [PipeLine].[Building Rating] = 
   CASE
     WHEN ((([PipeLine].[NDA Status])<>'No' And ([PipeLine].[Building Status])<>'No') AND (([PipeLine].[Deal With Partner])<>'No') AND (([PipeLine].LAND)<>'No') AND (([PipeLine].Connect)<>'No'))
      THEN 'A-'
     WHEN ((([PipeLine].[Building Status])<>'No' And ([PipeLine].[Building Status])<>'No') AND (([PipeLine].[Deal With Partner])<>'No'))
      THEN 'B'
   END;
```